# Sqlite disk I/O error on iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i got an app uses SQLite intensively,
it works perfect in the simulator, and also on iphone 4/4s

when i install in on iphone 5 and greater, i got this error:

```
Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (10: disk I/O error)
```

why is that happening only on iphone 5? there is 12 GB space free on the device.
thanks!

Comment: Where is the SQLite file located ?

Comment: Is it all on iOS7? In iOS 7 the default way sqlite treats updates to the database has changed, maybe you have a problem with that, considering you use it intensively ...

Comment: the database located in the documents folder,
its working fine on IOS 7 iphone 4,
but not in iphone > 5

i use "insert or replace" most of the time.

Comment: You can post your code ???
Maybe that way we can have more details to help you

Comment: I've seen some odd I/O errors when the device is locked (despite seemingly having the correct NSFileProtection / sqlite_open flags set).  Is the device locked when you see these errors?

Comment: are you updating the database on a thread that is not the main thread?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I would say that one possibility is that your database is locked because you didn't close some section, check on your code if you are opening the database somewhere "sqlite3_open(..." and not closing it, or returning before the call "sqlite3_finalize(..". Let me know if it solved your problem