# SQLite I/O Error on iOS 7.0 (with monotouch)

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin

We are currently developing an iPhone app with Xamarin's monotouch and use SQLite to store data. We use the latest version of the SQLite-component (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Unfortunately, we had some strange problems in the last few weeks. Everything works as designed, but after a while (between maybe 15-30min tracking, which generates GPS inserts into the database), the SQLite returns every database access with an I/O error:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: IOError
```

Disk space was available, also R/W-rights for the file were not the problem, because the first 30min everything worked...

So after a long Google research, I think the reason might be the same as here:

[CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773466/coredata-error-14-i-o-error-for-database)

Maybe also this issue here is related:
[Sqlite disk I/O error on iphone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139897/sqlite-disk-i-o-error-on-iphone-5)

As a workaround, we now deactivate the WAL (http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) with setting the journal_mode = OFF (http://www.stevemcarthur.co.uk/blog/post/some-kind-of-disk-io-error-occurred-sqlite/), but it's not the proper solution.

Which leads to my question: Is somebody out there who's got the same problem and found a real solution? And is my assumption correct that WAL with iOS 7.0 causes this problem? Or might there be another reason?

Comment: I have the same problem however I haven't had any luck setting the journal_mode to OFF.
I tried var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand ("PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF"); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery (); w/o any luck, I get a SQLite exception.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: string pragma = "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF";  
            SQLiteCommand cmd = this.CreateCommand(pragma);
                    
            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar<String>();

Comment: Thanks @u_b, I got this working early this morning by using ExecuteScalar. However, setting journal_mode to OFF didn't fix my problem. 
I tried querying the default journal_mode and it is "delete" instead of "wal" which is supposed to be the default in iOS 7.0 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/WhatsNew_CoreData_iOS/)
After I set it back to wal, it works as expected.
I'm confused and not sure what is going on here.
I'm posting on xamarin forum and will submit a support ticket too.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just posted it here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14083/sqlite-net-i-o-errors-in-when-the-app-is-in-the-background

Comment: @RacielR. lets discuss it in the xamarin forum and post a solution here if we find one :-)